# How to sort array by conditions in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    // sort: item,
    items: [{
        price: '1',
        name: 'vv'
      },
      {
        price: '22',
        name: 'vv'
      },
      {
        price: '55',
        name: 'vv'
      },
      {
        price: '77',
        name: 'vv'
      },
      {
        price: '123',
        name: 'vv'
      },
      {
        price: '53',
        name: 'vv'
      },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy(arr, key) {
      return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1
        if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1
        return 0
      })
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- v-for - sort array by name and price -->
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.message }} {{ item.name }}
  </li>
</ul>


<hr />
<div class="bbb">
  <button @click="sortbyname">name</buttton><br/>
<button @click="sortbyname">message</buttton>
</div>
```

How to sort array by name and price in Vuejs?

I have array of values, where I looped entire items and displayed initially, later. i have taken two buttons one for sorting array by name, and another for sorting array by val.

Comment: why is your price a string? It should be a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of `computed` properties.

**Logic**

- Loop the array with a computed property.
- Update the key fror sorting on button click, which makes the computed property to re execute.

You should not use duplicate computed properties. All your listing logic should be done in a single computed method as done below

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    // sort: item,
    sortKey: 'name',
    checked: false,
    searchString: "",
    items: [
      { price: '1', name: 'mm' },
      { price: '22', name: 'aa' },
      { price: '55', name: 'dd' },
      { price: '77', name: 'gg' },
      { price: '123', name: 'kk' },
      { price: '53', name: 'mn' },
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    sortedItems: function () {
      let searchString = this.searchString;
      const sortedArray = this.items.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[this.sortKey] < b[this.sortKey]) return -1
        if (a[this.sortKey] > b[this.sortKey]) return 1
        return 0
      });
      if (!searchString) { 
        return sortedArray;
      } else {
        searchString = searchString.trim().toLowerCase();
        const search_array = sortedArray.filter((item) => {
          if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
            return item;
          }
        });
        return search_array;
      }
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example-1">
  <ul>
    <input type="text" v-model="searchString" placeholder="Filter" />
    <p>sortKey = {{sortKey}}</p>
    <li v-for="item in sortedItems">
      <input class="checkbox-align" type="checkbox" :value="item.name" id="productname" v-model="item.checked" />
      {{ item.price }} - {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cecont" v-if="!checked">
    <p>text content</p>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="bbb">
    <button @click="sortKey = 'name'">name</buttton><br />
      <button @click="sortKey = 'price'">price</buttton>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using 2 `sortedItems` computed properties?

Comment: @Sundar You should not use duplicate computed properties. All your listing logic should be done in a single computed method. I have updated my fiddle